# Import UniqueConstraint from flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

i would like to use UniqueConstraint with flask_sqlalchemy

unfortunately, this import statement:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, UniqueConstraint
```

produces this error;

```
ImportError: cannot import name UniqueConstraint
```

what is the proper syntax for importing UniqueConstraint into a flask_sqlalchemy app?

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint
```